# Parameters in .NET Core docker launchSettings.json

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am writing an ASP.NET Core application and I have a `launchSettings.json` file with the following content:

```js
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50251",
      "sslPort": 44349
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "AspNetDockerDemo": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}"
    }
  }
}
```

**Question:** Where are the `{ }` placeholders substituded and where are the values definied by which they are substituted? What will I have to do if I want to define such values on my own?

Comment: Posting some of your code can make you question more clear and it's more likely to get accurate answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response - actually the `launchSettings.json` file is a configuration for VisualStudio to config the execution environment. So there is *no application code* that will handle this data. The quetion is by what values the parameters `Scheme` and `ServiceHost` in the execution environment are set/replaced.

Comment: What is your asp.net core version and vs version? I made a test with asp.net core and docker, but, I did not see this useage. Please share us more information about this useage you know.

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and Visual Studio 2017 (Version 15.8.5)

Answer (score 26):

This doesn't answer your question, but if you're asking because you want consistent host port numbers while debugging like I did, you can do this by adding `httpPort` and `sslPort` to the [launchSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-launch-settings?view=vs-2019) file.

[image]

Comment: "httpPort" and "sslPort" will map the specified host port to the container's port "80" and "443", respectively.

Answer (score 23):

Since you're using Visual Studio's Docker integration, you've obviously noted that it randomly selects port mappings for you.

One way to change this is to right click on your asp.net core app, select `Add -> Container Orchestration Support`.  This will attempt to regenerate your Dockerfile and .dockerignore files, which you may decline to do if you've made substantial modifications to your existing files (note: if you have, it may cause other issues with the following instructions).  It will also generate some docker-compose settings for you in the form of several yaml files.

In my case, I was interested in the docker-compose.override.yml file it added to the project.  Out of the box, it looks something like this:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  coreapp:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "80"
```

The `ports: = "80"` bit is what interests us.  Change it to `"<your desired port>:80"` to specify a port to use:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  coreapp:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Comment: Good god does this need more upvotes. This totally solved my issues trying to integrate an app with social media logins (i.e.: static callback URLs).

Comment: @EricSondergard how did you solve the issues eventually I am running into Social redirects as well trying to locally debug it

Comment: @Jean-Paul Yes, I did. I don't quite remember the exact situation, but I'll link you the project I was working on at the time. Hopefully you find what you need.

https://github.com/esond/blazor-crud

Comment: Perhaps, I missed something here, but is this as totally unrelated to the OP's question about where do the ServiceHost and Schema come from?  This is talking about ports, which was never asked about.  (Which I don't get the comment about needing more upvotes..)  And I never did see an answer about where to set the ServiceHost (I want to set it to 0.0.0.0 so it will map the port externally correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Create a .env file and assign Scheme and ServiceHost.

```
Scheme=schemename
ServiceHost=localhost
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by .env file. Can you provide a documentation link or a more clear description?

Comment: If u r using docker-compose, the root directory will have an .env file